# How do I delete data in a variable without deleting the variable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a program which you can add stuff to your shopping list.

```
shopping_list = ["Eggs", "Milk", "Bread"]
```

Now i know how to add and remove items, but how do i delete the string or number in a variable without losing the variable?

```
price = "£12"
```

If I do `del price` I destroy the variable.
If I try `print price` i get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    print price
NameError: name 'price' is not defined
```

Comment: You seem to have a mistaken mental model of how Python variables work. What do you think it would mean to delete a string? What would `print price` do after your desired operation?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're hoping to do, but maybe just set price to an empty string: `price = ""`

Comment: Why didn't i think of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do

```
price = None
```

Anything referenced by that variable will get garbage-collected.

Comment: If there's no other reference to that object, it'll get garbage-collected.